# Preforming segue and sending data using If condition

Tags: ios, swift, segue

I have 4 cells and each one of them has a label inside of it.

[image]

Every time a user clicks on a cell it will take them to a different view, and in that view I have a top label that should be named like the cell label. So if I clicked on cell 001 then the next page title label should be 001. Image below to show the title label:

[image]

I use prepare for segue to pass the value of the title label, however, how can I write a code that says:

```
if cell label = 001 {
   newViewTitle.text = cell label
}
```

This is my current prepare for segue code:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if let destination = segue.destination as? VolumeImgVC {


        if let VolumeNumLbl = volumEDnum as? String! {
            destination.Vtitle = VolumeNumLbl
        }
        if let VolumeNumLbl = volumEDnum1 as? String! {
            destination.Vtitle = VolumeNumLbl
        }
        if let VolumeNumLbl = volumEDnum2 as? String! {
            destination.Vtitle = VolumeNumLbl
        }

    }
}
```

The above code does not work and only executes the last if let statement.

Any suggestions please? Thank you

Comment: You want  to pass current cell Data to Next View Controller ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create a array of cellnamelabel array on click of cell just use the `tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow` property to get selected indexPath and pass the data

```
   override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
       if segue.identifier == "detailSeque" {
          if let destination = segue.destination as? VolumeImgVC {
             if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow {
                let volumeNum = volumeNumLblArray[indexPath.row]
                destination.Vtitle = volumeNum
             }
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: what do you mean by create a cell name label array on click of cell? how and where to do that? @suhit

Comment: refer this http://www.codingexplorer.com/segue-uitableviewcell-taps-swift/